# Is static needed when declaring const globals?

Tags: c++, static, linkage

often in headers I see

```
//global namespace, not in class
static const int my_global =1984;
```

but recently I learned that const implies internal linkage, so I wonder doesnt that make static unnecessary?

Comment: How do you feel things are contradictory/redundant? I don't see how they are. "static" will give the declaration internal linkage ***as well***, which is a different thing anyway. It's not redundant: unrelated

Comment: Without `static` there'd be a new definition of the variable every time the header is #included.

Comment: @acraig5075 I dont understand... header guards make sure qou include only once, even if you include 50x in your code with #include

Comment: @sehe: As the question says, it's redundant because constant global variables have internal linkage by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends.  In C++, it's unnecessary, but some people (myself included) like to put it in, on the grounds of saying what we mean.  And of course, if the header is to be used in C as well, it is necessary (but for many uses in C, you'll need a `#define`).

Answer (score 1):

In C++, it is unnecessary (redundant) to have the static keyword to prevent global linkage, since const does this for standard C++ (C++98, C++03, C++11).  In C, however, the static keyword is necessary for a variable to have local (file) linkage.   Since many C coding practices have been carried into C++ by habit (there is a lot of overlap), some people may bring this habit over without thinking.  I've heard it argued that the redundant static keyword in C++ to indicate non-global linkage helps C programmers understand.

I myself prefer the precision of programming in C++ with C++ idioms, so that we don't perpetuate C code in C++, which can lead to subtle errors, or at least waste and redundant code (such as habitual checking for NULL prior to calling delete on a pointer.